# Pushnotification : To external application iOS & android

Tags: android, ios, iphone, push-notification

Is it possible to implement the following scenario?

I have 2 applications

- app1
- app2

A notification is coming to app1 and the notification is the promotion for the app2
and if i click on that notification if the app2 is installed in the device app2 will open otherwise it should point to the appstore page of app2. [note: notification is send to app1]

Is it possible to make a functionality like this in iOS and Android?

Comment: Please let me know why you guys are -ve voting.Let me improvise my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do that..

As both apps are yours you know the launch activity and its package name. So whenever app1 gets push notification it can check whether app2 is installed using PackageManager and if app is not installed, intent for google play link with app2 package name will be opened.

You can refer these links 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html
http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#OpeningDetails

Answer (score 0):

ANDROID:
You can check if an app is installed by looking for the package name of app2 in your case(imagine com.example.app2)

```
  ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().
        getApplicationInfo(" com.example.app2", 0 );
```

When you send a notification, you can put extra fields in the notification JSON. Also you run your own code when the notification is clicked, so you can parse the custom JSON. Imagine the user clicks the notification the app1 would do the following:
-check if app2 is installed(the package name will comne in a extra_fielf of the notification)

```
if (true){open_app2();}

else{download_app2();}
```

On iOS i can´t help you.